# Wie sagt man "get beat up" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich gebe ein paar Beispiele an:

1. > My car really got beat up driving through the forest.
2. > Linebackers usually get pretty beaten up during the game (American football).

Mein Versuch einer Übersetzung:

1. > Mein Auto wurde richtig zusammengeschlagen, als wir durch den Wald gefahren sind.
2. > Linebackers werden schon viel bei Spielen zusammengeschlagen.

Comment: The literall translation of the bare word is *aufschlagen*, that does mean equally *zusammenschlagen* or *hit the floor*. The second almost fits the examples,. but not the intended semantics. Compare similarly *einschlagen* "impact".

Comment: No? The literal translation would be "aufgeschlagen werden" and that can only happen to books. "Sie haben ihre Bücher auf Seite 14 augeschlagen". The first example has nothing to do with punches, though. Literal translation is not useful here.

Comment: "Zusammengeschlagen werden" means physically being beaten up.
"Verprügelt werden" can be used in a metaphorical sense, but in the context of sports it means to lose heavily. It doesn't work with cars.

Comment: Bitte das englische Plural-s bei *Linebacker* nicht ins Deutsche übernehmen-das ist falsch

Answer (score 12):

The phrase you are looking for is "etwas abbekommen" or in stronger form "[richtig/ordentlich/ganz schön] etwas abbekommen" (colloquially etwas shortens to was).

> Mein Auto hat ordentlich was abbekommen, als wir durch den Wald gefahren sind.
>   Mein Auto hat ganz schön was abbekommen, als wir durch den Wald gefahren sind.
>
> Linebacker bekommen während des Spiels ordentlich was ab.

Edit:
You may also use "etwas mitmachen müssen" or "aushalten müssen".

> Mein Auto musste ganz schön was mitmachen/aushalten, als ich durch den Wald gefahren bin.
>
> Linebacker müssen während ihres Spiels ordentlich was aushalten.

Note that this doesn't necessarily imply damage. It can also mean that the suspension just go to good use.

Comment: *Einst wurde Apfelmus verschenkt und ich hab ordentlich was abbekommen. Dann hat jemand Wasser aus dem Fenster geschüttet, ich Stand drunter und hab was abbekommen.* "To get a share, part" is much wider, and less *impactful* than *beat* ... unless perhaps you think of *ab* "off", *ich bekomme es nicht ab* "it doesn't come off".

Comment: Well, it has multiple meanings, but I don't see how the above sentences are ambigious.

Comment: It ambiguous about the degree of damage. It sounds too nice, not rough enough. There are many idioms in that register, *mitgenommen sein*, *etwas haben einstecken müssen*. Comparing the entries for the Germanic roots of *böse*, *bad* and *beat*, one can find similarities, but I see no connection. Nevertheless would "böse was abkriegen, abbekommen" surely more significantly transfer the meaning.

Comment: @vectory "*Ganz schön* was abbekommen" or "*Ordentlich* was abbekommen" do sound nice on a literal level... but here they are idiomatic/euphemistic. The same way the *pretty* is used in the second English example.

Answer (score 5):

*ramponiert werden* ist eine schöne Übersetzung, die auf beide deiner Beispiele passt:

> Mein Auto wurde ordentlich ramponiert als wir durch den Wald gefahren sind
>
> Linebacker werden während des Spiels ordentlich ramponiert

*zusammengeschlagen werden* passt für beide deiner Beispiele nicht (für die Linebacker bedeutet es etwas anderes als *getting beat up*, für das Auto passt es gar nicht)

Comment: Im ersten Beispiel paßt das gut, aber im zweiten?

Comment: für den zweiten Satz würde ich das nehmen, was vectory in seinem Kommentar schon erwähnte (ist wohl in der Aufzählung etwas untergegangen): *Linbacker müssen während des Spiels einiges/ganz schön viel einstecken*

Answer (score 1):

"Get beat up" has multiple meanings, and "zusammengeschlagen werden" doesn't cover all of them. "Jemanden zusammenschlagen" basically means to clobber somebody, to give somebody a (severe) beating. So the phrase doesn't fit with your examples.

A fitting phrase might be "jemanden / etwas durch die Mangel drehen", "to put somebody / something through the wringer". With that, your example sentences would be

> Ich habe mein Auto richtig durch die Mangel gedreht, als wir durch den Wald fuhren.
>
> Linebackers werden während des Spiels oft richtig durch die Mangel gedreht.

Comment: I disagree. "Jemanden durch die Mangel drehen" means to put severe preasure on someone, harassing or threatening them. It does not mean to cause actual, physical damage.

Comment: Not sure where "die Mangel" is from, but if a relation to "to munch" or Fr. "manger" is found, then "chewed up" comes to mind. But that doesn't strike me as likely, as "to mangle" relates, although it's hard to find a trace of a root beyond Latin. Wiktionary glosses "to put through the wringer" as *scrutinize*, which reminds of *Abklopfen* that does for better or worse translate the parts of *beat up* quite well (I arrived at the thought picturing the car having to be scrutinized for damage after driving through the woods; does knock it up work in that case? not really).

Comment: en.wikt gives "putzen" as [cognate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/bautan%C4%85) to "beat", though the page for *putzen* mentions that several theories exist. Anyhow, ein Auto wird nicht durch die Mangel gedreht, das sagt keiner. *abreiben, aufreiben* vielleicht? Auch nicht. Aber irgendwas in der Richtung fände ich nicht schlecht.

Comment: @jarnbjo Maybe you're thinking of "jemanden in die Mangel nehmen"?

Comment: @vectory The "Mangel" in this expression refers to the actual [mangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangle_(machine)). If you were put through one of those, you'd be a bit disheveled, to say the least ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Mein Auto wurde richtig **durchgeschüttelt**, als wir durch den Wald
>   gefahren sind.
>
> Linebackers werden bei Spielen ganz schön **abgeklopft**.

*Ramponiert werden*, *was abbekommen* und *durch die Mangel gedreht werden* gefallen mir auch, teils besser, teils weniger.

Ein ramponiertes Auto hat mindestens Dellen und Kratzer. Auch wenn es etwas abbekommen hat gehe ich von sichtbaren, bleibenden Schäden aus. Beim Sportler vielleicht nur blaue Flecken, die nach ein paar Tagen verschwinden. Durchgeschüttelt worden zu sein ist da noch etwas zurückhaltender.

Durch die Mangel drehen verwendet man als Metapher fürs Foltern - das ist für den Sport schon ein ziemlich harter Ausdruck, aber vielleicht gerade gewollt.

Comment: Abgeklopft wie ein Teppich oder beim Spielerwechsel im Fußball? Das klingt viel zu harmlos mMn.

Comment: Nun ja, to beat heißt auch schlagen, klopfen, ... - aber ich kenne die englische Verwendung nicht so gut, um die Nuancen beurteilen zu können. "Die Nr. 10 wurde von der gegnerischen Mannschaft reihum abgeklopft" ist ziemlich verharmlosend. Das heißt schon mindestens blaue Flecken.

Comment: Ich verstehe darunter einen sportlichen/freundschaftlichen Schlag auf die Schulter. Auch der Polizist kann die Hosentaschen in einer Durchsuchung abklopfen. Ich verbinde nichts gewalttätiges damit.  Auch der Duden nicht. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abklopfen Bist Du Ösi oder Schweizer?

Comment: Weder noch. Freundschaftliche Schläge kenne ich als Abklatschen.

Comment: Nachdem ich *abgeklopft* selbst in die Runde geworfen hatte, finde ich es im Bsp. doch nicht passend, weil es nicht idiomatisch ist (was beim Sport in Sachen Zugehörigkeit zeigen relativ wichtig ist). War auch nur eine theoretische Überlegung. Zu der fiel mir noch ein, dass English "check-up" und "body-check" ungefähr das ausdrücken, was ich dachte. Liefert aber soweit ich sehe auch keine Erfolg versprechenden Ansatz.

Answer (score 0):

> **geschunden**

[schinden](https://dwds.de/wb/schinden)* ist ein pejoratives verb, das in beiden Bsp. im Sinne von *belasten [bis an die Grenzen] und dabei Schaden zufügen* passt. Das Partizip lautet *geschunden*.

Falls *beat-up* nicht so derbe ist, wie ich denke, wäre die Übersetzung leicht sarkastisch. dict.cc nennt *to be beat-up* - De. *upgefuckt*. Wiktionary erklärt es als "Worn out by overuse; in a state of disrepair", noch ohne Übersetzung. Weitere Wörterbücher ... siehe dort.

Comment: Meinen Sie abgefuckt?